# Registry does not like long filename for shell commands or verbs

Tags: windows, windows-vista, registry, filenames

(if not applicable to SO, please refer to another appropriate place, thanks).

When using the registry to associate file extensions and application, I put in the full filename of my application, but that does not work well, only if I use the 8.3 filename.

for example ( taken from the registry) this works:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Toto.Document\shell\myVerb\command]
@="C:\\my\\path\\bin\\Debug\\bin\\myexe_~1.EXE /dde"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Toto.Document\shell\myVerb\ddeexec]
@="[myVerb(\"%1\")]"
```

but this does not work :

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Toto.Document\shell\myVerb\command]
@="C:\\my\\path\\bin\\Debug\\bin\\myexecutable.EXE /dde"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Toto.Document\shell\myVerb\ddeexec]
@="[myVerb(\"%1\")]"
```

The action is called by right-clicking on the file in Explorer, I get the error : 
"Windows cannot find 'c:\users\me\desktop\tata.toto'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again".

---

I'm creating the keys programatically with CRegKey and using GetModuleFileName to get the application path.

2 questions : 
- I'm probably missing something in my registry entry ? (i've tried quoting the paths, but does not work)
- Can I get the "short" filename ? (searching a little bit seems that GetShortPath should work, but not always!)

Thanks.

Max.

---

(edit 22/03/2011)
I tried using quotes but it did not work (with /dde)
I decided to use normal parameters instead of /dde and it seems to work nicely with the normal path (not shortened like stated above).

I'm still not certain why when creating a simple MFC SDI project it will write out registry values with the old short name instead of the long name.

Thanks again.

Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the key with another couple of double-quotes (note between `.EXE` and `/dde`:

```
@="C:\\my\\path\\bin\\Debug\\bin\\myexecutable.EXE" "/dde"
```

Comment: The reason for this suggestion is that, although your example path doesn't include spaces, your real path does. We can tell even from here!

Comment: :) Raymond Chen calls it "psychic debugging".

Comment: @David @Max will have to pretty soon, or people will stop answering his questions.

Comment: sorry about that, will try to be a better citizen.

Comment: I tried adding quotes and it still did not work. I worked around the problem by not using "/dde" and just use normal parameters instead. (I will edit the original post).

Comment: accepted the answer, should be working, but in my case did not, so I used a work-around.
Max.